# split a string into sequences of consecutive non-whitespace characters

Tags: c++, regex

I want to split a string into sequences of consecutive non-whitespace characters. For example, given

`std::string test("  35.3881 12.3637 39.3485");`,

I want to obtain an iterator which points to "35.3881", its increment points to "12.3637" and the second increment points to "39.3485".

As in the given example, it's possible (but not guaranteed) that the string starts with an unknown number of whitespaces. Moreover, the number of whitespaces between sequences of non-whitespace characters is also unknown. Trailing whitespaces are possible too.

The following code almost solves my problem:

```
std::regex regex("\\s+");
std::sregex_token_iterator it(test.cbegin(), test.cend(), regex, -1);
```

The problem, even with the given example, is that here the iterator `it` initially points to an empty string; which is not the behavior I desire. How can we fix that?

Comment: Well, if you add a whitespace character on the front, you eliminate the "might or might not start with whitespace" complication, and always get an empty string first, which you can simply skip over.

Answer (score 3):

I'd just use a normal stream_iterator:

```
std::istringstream test("  35.3881 12.3637 39.3485");

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(test),
          {},
          std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Result:

```
35.3881
12.3637
39.3485
```

If, as noted in the comments, you find it important to avoid copying the data, you can use an `istrstream` instead of an `instringstream`, something like this:

```
#include <strstream>
// ...

std::string test("  35.3881 12.3637 39.3485");
std::istrstream buffer(test.c_str());
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(buffer),
          {},
          std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Note: `<strstream>` and everything contains is officially deprecated, so in theory, it could disappear in some future version of the standard. I'd eventually expect to see something based on a `string_view`, which would also avoid copying the data, but I'm not sure it actually exists yet (it certainly doesn't in the compiler I'm using at the moment).

Comment: or `float` or `double`, instead of `std::string`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: The example he shows would work with `float` or `double`, but what he specifies is just "sequences of consecutive non-whitespace characters", so it could just as easily be something like `abcd` or `123e13e4`, neither of which would parse as a floating point number.

Comment: Can we modify your code such that `test` is still a `std::string`? Clearly, we can declare a `std::istringstream ss(test)` and use `ss` in place of `test` in your code, but the ctor of `istringstream` will make a copy of `test` which I would like to avoid.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: I've added at least one way to do it that avoids copying the data.

Comment: Do you've got a concrete idea how we could modify your code such that it uses `std::string_view`?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Sure. You'd derive a streambuf that works with a string view instead of a char * like a `strstream` uses. One obvious implementation of that would be to derive from `strsteambuf`, and have it take a `string_view` as an argument, and pass its its argument's `data()` as the argument to the underlying `strstreambuf`. From there, you use `rdbuf()` to tell an `istrstream` to use that buffer.

Comment: I was interested in a `stirng_view` solution, cause `istrstream` is deprecated. Since `strstreambuf ` is deprecated too, do you know another solution?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: The obvious would be to pretty much duplicate `strstreambuf` separately. Personally, I wouldn't worry much about it being deprecated though--when/if it disappears is soon enough to change to something else. I see little reason to believe it'll disappear soon.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that there is no built-in solution for this problem. And even when it's trivial to write my own buffer, it lets a simple thing look complicated. Couldn't we simple use `std::istringstream iss; iss.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(const_cast<std::string&>(s).data(), s.size());`, where `std::string const& s` is provided?

Comment: @0xbadf00d: I think it's mostly a consequence of `string_view` being a relatively recent addition, so nobody's gotten around to adding versions of everything else that would benefit from accepting a `string_view`.

Comment: What do you think about the following solution using a user-defined `streambuf` and `istream`? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=d4a9a9ef4a6c59fe. Are there any issues which might occur (I know almost nothing about the I/O library)? And what would be a good name for my `foo` class?